# new git branch up to date but can't push new files and folders

Tags: git

I have created a new branch named "new_code". I have more files in the code and I want to push everything to this new branch.
After `git push origin new_code` I have the same files and folders in the new_code branch as I have in my main branch.
But I don't have the newer files, I want to have all the project folders and files in the new branch. Forcing a push didn't help either.  `git status`
`On branch new_code nothing to commit, working tree clean`
How can I update my branch, I don't mind deleting it and start new

Comment: Git doesn't store folders at all (only files whose names contain forward slashes), and `git push` does not push *files*, but rather *commits*. To see the files *in* some particular commit, you check out that commit: Git then extracts the files, and if a file is named `path/to/file`, Git makes sure that your OS is happy by creating folders `path` (at top level) and `to` (in `path`) and then creating a file named `file` in `path/to`. But to Git this is just a file named `path/to/file`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new branch on the remote site you have to use

```
git push $REMOTE $LOCAL_BRANCH_NAME:$REMOTE_BRANCH_NAME
```

So in your case it'd be `git push origin new_code:new_code`

Comment: This is the response: Everything up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

workflow to use new branch:

```
git checkout master # starting point
git pull # make sure all is up to date
git checkout -b new_code # create new branch
touch f1 # make some changes
git add . # stage all the changes
git commit -m "changes in f1 are awesome" # commit change
git push -u origin new_code # push and track new branch
```

generally to see what is going on use:

```
git status
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get your actual branch with : `git status`, the name will be after `On branch`. Copy this name.

- Add your files with `git add .`
- Add a commit message with `git commit -m "your changes message"`
- Then you can do : `git push origin localBranchName:RemoteBranch -f`

ex:
If `git status` return `On branch main`
To push on new_code branch you need to do: `git push origin main:new_code`